# Independence of two white noise processes

Tags: time-series, independence, white-noise

Say I have two white noise processes $e_{t}\sim WN\left(0,\,\sigma^{2}\right)$ and $u_{t}\sim WN\left(0,\,\sigma^{2}\right)$. Can I say that these two processes are independent or do I need to make additional assumptions to make this claim?

**EDIT**
The question stems from an article which I was reading. In the article it was stated that $e_{t}$ and $u_{t}$ are zero-mean white noise processes. I was wondering if I can interpret this statement as if $e_{t}$ and $u_{t}$ are independent. That $e_{t}$ and $u_{t}$ are zero-mean white noise processes is all the information given about these two terms except for that they are the residuals in the vector autoregression:$$\left[\begin{array}{c}
x_{t}\\
y_{t}
\end{array}\right]=\Pi\left[\begin{array}{c}
x_{t-1}\\
y_{t-1}
\end{array}\right]+\left[\begin{array}{c}
e_{t}\\
u_{t}
\end{array}\right]$$

Comment: Please clarify the question. In what sense do you 'have' the processes and in what sense do you want to be able to 'say' they are independent? It seems clear that 1. you can define such processes to be independent, 2. independence is not guaranteed without extra assumptions (for a counterexample, let $e_t$ be such a process, and define $u_t=e_t$ for all $t$).

Comment: Or is this a terminology question: whether the first sentence of the question is typically interpreted to contain the assumption that $e$ and $u$ are independent?

Comment: @JuhoKokkala. Yes its more a terminology thing. I was reading an article in where they specified two mean zero white noise processes as above. I was wondering if I can conclude that the two processes are independent from this.

Comment: Please edit this information into the question.